# How do I compare two large 2D arrays in Python for exact equality?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

As stated in the title. I am trying to compare two large(21x21) grids containing elments of single dots and single dashes to see if each element at each index is the same. Using `array1 == array2` produces the following error:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

However, I have not encountered a good explanation of the a.all/a.any syntax. What goes before the dot? What params do they take?

Edit: I have been avoiding using NumPy, but theres no way around it. NumPy is imported.
Any ideas?

Portion of the code where I am creating a default grid of dots and dashes:

```
defaultgrid = [['.' for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]

for x in range(1, 21, 2):
    defaultgrid[x] = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
                      " ", " "]

for x in range(0, 21, 2):
    defaultgrid[x] = [".", " ", ".", " ", ".", " ", ".", " ", ".", " ", ".", " ", ".", " ", ".", " ", ".", " ", ".",
                      " ", "."]
```

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about that error message here.

Comment: That error comes from numpy. Why are you using that if you're not allowed?

Comment: Just use nested lists, and `list1 == list2` should do what you want.

Comment: thats the thing, I havent even imported numpy! I dont understand how i'm getting that error

Comment: probably you have imported something else that imports numpy.

Comment: I am using pycharm, and there are no imports at the top of my file. I could copy/paste the program here but its something like 160 lines

Comment: How are you creating `array1` and `array2`? Whatever you used uses numpy internally.

Comment: I am adding the portion that declares the arrays

Comment: Probably you have to post all 160 lines of code for us to be able to find out the source of problem.

Comment: Ah, sorry my terminology might be wrong. Perhaps these are 2 Matrices and not arrays?

Comment: What you showed above is a list of lists, which is being used to represent a matrix. Did you use a similar technique to create the other array you're comparing with?

Comment: This default array is passed into a function that "engraves" a pattern onto it, and I am then trying to compare two engravings to see if they are the same. So yes, the 2 arrays are of the same size and use the same symbols.

Comment: Actually, I'm a putz and you're right. I couldnt figure out how to copy the default grid without linking the 2 and ended up using numpy.copy(), so not using NumPy is already out the window. I take back my objection to NumPy. Used it in one line and forgot I had it

Comment: So if you use numpy then instead of comparing `if arr1 == arr2:` you do `if np.all(arr1 == arr2):` or do `if np.array_equal(arr1, arr2):`.

Comment: You **absolutely do not need numpy to copy a list**. That is a total absurd reason to use numpy

Comment: @Arty, it is worth to mention that ```np.array_equal(arr1, arr2)``` is more strict than ```np.all(arr1 == arr2)``` since ```np.all``` will take into account broadcasting.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The error message suggests that OP is using numpy for ```array1``` and ```array2```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga normally yes, but its a nested list and using arr1 = arr2 links the two so that changes to one affect the other. So either I create a new list and copy each element manually, or i lose a few points for numpy. I'm choosing the latter.

Comment: `arr1 = arr2`. **never copies anything in python**, regardless of whether or not it is a nested list. If you want to copy a nested list, just use `arr1 = [a[:] for a in arr2]`. Numpy is **never necessary to copy  lists**

Answer (score 1):

How about comparing the strings of the arrays?

Str(arr1) == str(arr2)

Comment: This really shouldn't be used, it's super hackey

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga for that particular case (' ' / '.' array) it's actually a good workaround

Comment: @KiJéy no it absolutely is not. You just need `(arr1 == arr2).all()`

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that you want to use Numpy then a way to solve your error `The truth value of an array.....` is following:

1. If you have two numpy arrays `arr1` and `arr2` then everywhere compare them for equality not by `if arr1 == arr2:` but by `if np.array_equal(arr1, arr2):`.
2. Alternatively if you're sure that your two arrays have same size (dimensionality) and type then you can compare them for equality also like this `if np.all(arr1 == arr2):`.
3. If you don't use Numpy then two nested lists can be just compared as `if arr1 == arr2:`.

You were saying that you used numpy only to do `np.copy()`. To make a deep copy of a list you can use standard [copy.deepcopy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) (you have to `import copy`).